# Application Verifier limits Heap Allocations by default?

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, application-verifier

I'm currently testing an application that has to open big files in Application Verifier 6.3 for 64 bit systems. My application **must** be able to allocate around 100 - 200 MB of memory which worked nicely in debug and release mode before.

This is the code I use for allocating the memory:

```
[...]
char* fileStream;
try
{
   fileStream = new char[fileLength]; // The fileLength is usually about 100 000 000 and 200 000 000
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& ba)
{
   MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to allocate enough memory for the required operation", "Not enough memory", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
   return;
}
[...]
```

I added the Application to the Application Verifier and enabled all Basic Tests:

[image]

Now, strangely, `new char[fileLength]` always returns `NULL` for a file being 97 MB big! Which obviously caused access violations later on. So now I'm having more problems than before...

Does the Application Verifier apply some Heap Allocation limits by default? Can I disable them somehow?

Comment: `Which obviously caused access violations later on.`  Maybe you should fix this bug in your code.  App Verifier seems to be a blessing in disguise.  Also, you say "returns NULL", but a `new[]` failure throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception, and doesn't return NULL.  You even have in your code a `catch` block for that exception.  So you need to clarify what is going on.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Several answers on other questions in the internet show that Application Verifier makes the new operator to return `NULL` by default when you try to alloc more than it limits you. Usually new throws `bad_alloc` as long as you dont define something, which I haven't done. I was surprised by this aswell. Also the code below cannot be reached in normal behaviour, cus the bad_alloc would be thrown first and the function would return before using the pointer.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's pointless to use App Verifier for this test if it doesn't do the "right thing", and especially if you have faithfully attempted to catch `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, but I have a heap corruption error from time to time later on in my program (when the execution of this code is long gone) and I need to find that via the Application Verifier :s

Comment: You'll have to set [Conserve Memory to Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220922%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you a lot for this important tip sir! I have troubles finding that setting in Visual Studio 2013. It seems to be in the property page in VS2005 and VS2008. Do you have any Idea where it is in VS2013?